# Getting parent enitity of enitityreference field

Tags: entities

Is there a function to get parent enityinfo to which entityreference field is attached. Similar function is hostEntity() provided by field_collection.

I created the content type which has enityform as enitityreference field.Enityform contains basic contact field with additional computed field.
In that field I need nid of node to which entityform is attached.Using entity_metadata_wrapper I am able to get info about entityform object using below code.

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity_type, $entity);  
$info=$wrapper->entityInfo();
```

Any idea how to further backtrack and get parent node id?

Update : Entityform is attached to a node([ref](http://www.sixmiletech.com/content/embedding-entiyform-node#.UeGJhmRAToE)).
1.Node contains entity reference field, to which enitity form is attached.
2.Enityform contains computed field.
3.In computed field when the above mentioned code executed, field $wrapper gets the details about enitityform object(should be because computed field belongs to this entity).
4.As there will be no relation between node and the attached entityfrom after submission, I am trying to capture the NID of node during the form submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this issue in Entityform queue https://drupal.org/node/2041349

This person had the same problem.  You can do this without programming if you use the [Entity Reference Current](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference_current) module.

You will need to attach an Entity Reference field to the Entityform Type and have the field use the **Entity Reference current behavior**.

Comment: ,nice catch. you are throwing me back to my own thread :). You get what i Mean ? ;). I was expecting some other alternative solutions from SO brains thats why I kept this issue open here.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
// Load wrapper
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity_type, $entity);  
// Load parent entity
$parent = $wrapper->field_entityreference->value();
// Get nid
$nid = $parent->field_computed_field->value();
// Debug output
drupal_set_message(t('Parent NID: @nid', array('@nid' => $nid)));
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question or information is not good enough. So I have updated the question with additional details.